# Coordinates drawing on pictureBox Image

Tags: c#, system.drawing, aforge

I am trying to draw on picturebox and my code is below:

```
List<IntPoint> edgePoints;
List<IntPoint> corners;

AForge.Imaging.Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox2.Image);
Pen bluePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 5);

double[] blobAdjustedSize = new double[blobs.Length];
for (int i = 0, n = blobs.Length; i < n; i++)
{
    edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blobs[i]);
    corners = PointsCloud.FindQuadrilateralCorners(edgePoints);

    g.DrawPolygon(bluePen, corners); // **UNDERLINE**
}
```

And I am getting an error. `g.DrawPolygon(bluePen, corners)` is underlined.

The error is:

> The best overloaded method match for System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawPolygon(System.Drawing.Pen, System.Drawing.Point[])" has some invalid arguments

Comment: error mentions it. You are not supplying corrects parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It's expecting an [Array of Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0c4s09%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than a List, define corners as an [Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or add

```
using System.Linq;
```

To the top of the file, and change the line to

```
g.DrawPolygon( bluePen, corners.ToArray());
```

Comment: You need to pass an Array of CLR Point objects into the method, it probably doesn't like the aForge IntPoint, you'll need to coerce their class into the .NET point class

Comment: It is logical @Rich. Probably you are right. But when I changed, edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blobs[i]);
    corners = PointsCloud.FindQuadrilateralCorners(edgePoints); lines getting error. :) I am only calculating values, not drawing screen. :) It is solve for now. Thanks for help.